# How to subscribe to "HttpClientResponse::toFlowable()" outside of the vert.x "rxResponse().subscribe" callback

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying to use the content of an `HttpClientResponse.toFlowable()` outside of the event loop, using an AtomicReference to hold the Flowable.

So, I've set up a test which returns the body, then fails during the trailer decoding. Thus, my subscription to the flowable should receive the response body, then an error.

That's what I observe when I subscribe to the Flowable right after (still in the callback), but not when subscribing to the flow outside of the callback. In the latter case my test pass 1/3 of the time...

[The vertx-rx doc](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java3/#_vert_x_api_for_rxjava3) clearly says that it's a hot flowable and should be either subscribed in the event loop OR paused.

So, I've tried to pause the response before subscribing but I get the same test results : only 1/3 of my runs got both the body and the exception.

Moreover, when looking at the Vert.x `HttpClientResponse::toFlowable()` implementation, I can see that a `readStream.pause()` is made anyway.

So my question is ... **Am I missing something ? Or could it be a Vert.x bug ?**

Here is the code I'm using :

```java
package my.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.rxjava3.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.rxjava3.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.rxjava3.core.http.HttpClient;
import io.vertx.rxjava3.core.net.NetServer;

public class VxTestRx3 {
    static NetServer server;
    static HttpClient client;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
        server = startServer();
        client = Vertx.vertx()
                      .createHttpClient();
    }

    @RepeatedTest(1000)
    void shouldReachOnNextAndOnError() throws Exception {

        CountDownLatch bodyReadLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch responseReadyToRead = new CountDownLatch(1);
        AtomicReference<Flowable<Buffer>> flowableRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        AtomicInteger ab = new AtomicInteger(0);
        client.rxRequest(HttpMethod.GET,
                         server.actualPort(),
                         "localhost",
                         "/")
              .subscribe(request -> {
                  request.rxResponse()
                         .subscribe(response -> {
                             // even with "response.pause()" here, the test is failing.
                             flowableRef.set(response.toFlowable());
                             responseReadyToRead.countDown();
                             // If the Flowable is subscribed here : I get my onNext & onError called.
                             /*flowableRef.get()
                                        .doOnComplete(bodyReadLatch::countDown)
                                        .subscribe(buffer -> ab.addAndGet(1),
                                                   t -> {
                                                       ab.addAndGet(2);
                                                       bodyReadLatch.countDown();
                                                   });*/
                         });
                  Flowable.<Buffer>empty().subscribe(request.toSubscriber());
              });
        responseReadyToRead.await();
        // If the Flowable is subscribed here : the behaviour is not stable.
        flowableRef.get()
                   .doOnComplete(bodyReadLatch::countDown)
                   .subscribe(buffer -> ab.addAndGet(1),
                              t -> {
                                  ab.addAndGet(2);
                                  bodyReadLatch.countDown();
                              });
        bodyReadLatch.await();
        // Should have been in onNext then onError callbacks.
        Assertions.assertThat(ab.get()).isEqualTo(3);
    }

    // This starts a server synchronously.
    // It serves a static HTTP response with an illegal trailer name (making Vert.x fail)
    private static NetServer startServer() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch serverReady = new CountDownLatch(1);
        AtomicReference<NetServer> servRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        Vertx.vertx().createNetServer()
                                .connectHandler(socket -> {
                                    String content1 = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                                            + "transfer-encoding: chunked\r\n"
                                            + "\r\n"
                                            + "2\r\n"
                                            + "OK"
                                            + "\r\n"
                                            + "0\r\n"
                                            + "é: trailerValue\r\n" // é is an invalid trailer name
                                            + "\r\n";
                                    // Read the request content, then write content, then close the socket.
                                    socket.handler(b -> socket.write(content1).subscribe(socket::close));
                                })
                                .listen()
                .subscribe(netServer -> {
                    servRef.set(netServer);
                    serverReady.countDown();
                });
        serverReady.await();
        return servRef.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after more searches I've found out what happened.

### Simplification

First, I've re-created a test removing the use of rx-vert, and added an exception handler on the socket :

```java
package org.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientRequest;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetServer;
import io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream;

public class VxTestNonRx {
    static NetServer server;
    static HttpClient client;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
        server = startServer();
        client = Vertx.vertx().createHttpClient();
    }

    @RepeatedTest(10000)
    void shouldReachOnNextAndOnError() throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch bodyReadLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch responseReadyToRead = new CountDownLatch(1);
        AtomicReference<ReadStream<Buffer>> readStreamRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        AtomicInteger ab = new AtomicInteger(0);
        client.request(HttpMethod.GET,
                       server.actualPort(),
                       "localhost",
                       "/")
              .compose(HttpClientRequest::send)
              .onSuccess(response -> {
                  // Catches exceptions when they happen before we subscribed to the ReadStream
                  response.netSocket().exceptionHandler(t -> System.out.println("NET EXCEPTION HANDLER" + t.getMessage()));
                  //response.pause(); // Try to pause FIRST to avoid skipping buffers
                  // When handlers are set here : 
                  //  - with pause(): 100% times exceptionHandler only.
                  //  - without pause(): 100% times : handler, then exceptionHandler
                  readStreamRef.set(response);
                  responseReadyToRead.countDown();
              });
        responseReadyToRead.await();
        // When handlers are set here : 
        // - without pause() : 
        //     - 66% times : handler, then exceptionHandler
        //     - 33% times : only exceptionHandler gets called.
        // - with pause() : 
        //     - 99% times : only onError gets called 
        //     - 1% times  : netSocket().exceptionHandler, then handler gets called. (but neither endHandler nor exceptionHandler are called !)
        readStreamRef.get()
                     .handler(buffer -> {
                         System.out.println("HANDLER");
                         ab.addAndGet(1);
                     })
                     .endHandler(unused -> {
                         System.out.println("END HANDLER");
                         bodyReadLatch.countDown();
                     })
                     .exceptionHandler(t -> {
                         System.out.println("ERROR HANDLER");
                         ab.addAndGet(2);
                         bodyReadLatch.countDown();
                     });
        readStreamRef.get().resume();
        bodyReadLatch.await();
        // Should have been in onNext then onError callbacks.
        Assertions.assertThat(ab.get()).isEqualTo(3);
    }

    // This starts a server synchronously.
    // It serves a static HTTP response with an illegal trailer name (making Vert.x fail)
    private static NetServer startServer() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch serverReady = new CountDownLatch(1);
        AtomicReference<NetServer> servRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        Vertx.vertx().createNetServer()
             .connectHandler(socket -> {
                 String content1 = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                         + "transfer-encoding: chunked\r\n"
                         + "\r\n"
                         + "2\r\n"
                         + "OK"
                         + "\r\n"
                         + "0\r\n"
                         + "é: trailerValue\r\n" // é is an invalid trailer name
                         + "\r\n";
                 // Read the request content, then write content, then close the socket.
                 socket.handler(b -> socket.write(content1, ar -> socket.close()));
             })
             .listen()
             .onSuccess(netServer -> {
                 servRef.set(netServer);
                 serverReady.countDown();
             });
        serverReady.await();
        return servRef.get();
    }
```

### Observations

As written in java comments, here are my findings :

- When `ReadStream` handlers are set right after getting the response:

  - When `pause()`ing the ReadStream first: I don't get any buffers, `ReadStream.exceptionHandler` is ALWAYS called.
  - without `pause()`: I ALWAYS receive the body buffer in `ReadStream.handler`, then `ReadStream.exceptionHandler` gets called.
- When handlers are set outside of the response received callback context:

  - When `pause()`ing the ReadStream first (still in the callback context):

    - 99% of the time: only `ReadStream.exceptionHandler` gets called
    - 1% of the time: `netSocket().exceptionHandler` is called, then handler gets called but neither `ReadStream.endHandler` nor `ReadStream.exceptionHandler` get called, the stream "never ends" !!
  - without `pause()ing`:

    - 66% of the time: `ReadStream.handler` is called, then `ReadStream.exceptionHandler`.
    - 33% of the time: ONLY `ReadStream.exceptionHandler` gets called.

### Explanations

When setting the handlers directly in the "response received" callback, the behaviour is stable, and this can help to understand how `ReadStream.pause()` work.

When pausing, Vert.x will not stop to read the response content. It will buffer the ByteBuffers to be able to serve them either on `ReadStream.fetch(x)` or `ReadStream.resume()`.
But when it encounters an error (in my case, while reading the trailers, after the body buffers) it will still call the callback set with `ReadStream.exceptionHandler`. In that case, the body has not been read (because of the pause), but the pre-defined exceptionHandler has been called.

However, without any `ReadStream.pause()`, as soon as the event "response received" ends, the request's buffers (that's another eventloop event) will be sent to the registered `ReadStream.handler` directly, then vert.x will find the error out and calls the registered `ReadStream.exceptionHandler`.

This explains my stable cases nicely. Now, let's explain the unstable ones !

When setting the `ReadStream`'s Handlers outside of the scope of the "response received" promise, it's possible to miss some events. That's quite simple, when vert.x gets out of the "response received" scope, that's the end of an event, then :

- Vert.x process the buffers (or skip them and save them when pausing) as part of other events, probably on the same event loop, but the `ReadStream.handler` registration is made outside of the context this time ! That's another thread and this code may have not run already ! So buffers sent to the ReadStream will be lost.
- Worse, when the trailer error is found out, if there is no exception handler set already, Vert.x will fall back on the next exception handler it can get : the TCP connection one (`response.netSocket().exceptionHandler`), or if not set neither... the event loop exception handler, and so on. So the error is ... lost, even when pausing the stream.

This explains why, when defining my handlers outside of the "response received event" context, my registered `ReadStream.handler` was not always called (the buffer event had been sent before the registration). But luckily the exception happened after my exception handler registration in 99% of the time. The last 1% is now explained, neither the handler, nor the exceptionHandler had been registered while vert.x processed the exception...

### How does that apply to the initial rx-vertx issue ?

Well... calling `response.toFlowable()` maps the `ReadStream` handlers to `Flowable`s upcoming subscription.
But again, the subscription to the resulting Flowable happened outside of the scope of "response received event". Thus events may have flowed before actually subscribing !

### Eventually, is that a vert.x issue ?

Well... No. I was misusing it.

But it could be good to fail the `ReadStream`'s handler/endHandler/exceptionHandler registration when `ReadStream` terminal methods (endHandler/exceptionHandler) have been called already.
Thus we would never wait forever for a `ReadStream` to publish Buffers, and could get clearer exception messages !